# How to check if a property exists in a multidimensional object using variables to compose the name?

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript object like this, let's call it store:

```
{
  area1: {my product name: 'red'}
}
```

I want to check if a specific value exists in store, using hasOwnProperty.
Assuming that I have all these values already defined in properties, like area, productName and color, how can I check if **store** has a **area** property ans this one also has a **productName** property?

I basically would like to do something like

```
const res = store.hasOwnProperty(area[productName]) && store[area][productName]=== color;
```

which seems not to work.

Comment: Is `area` a string or an object? `area[productName]` means it's an object but `store[area][productName]` doesn't make sense

Comment: What you want might be `const res = store[area]?.[productName] === color`